# Disparar evento ao mudar valor de um textBox C#

Tags: c#, eventos, textbox, winforms

Galera, estou iniciando em c# e estou com um problema. Estou trabalhando com Windows form.
Estou usando o evento TextChange em um textbox, e a cada tecla pressionada no campo ele dispara o evento. Preciso que o evento seja disparado somente quando o valor do campo estiver totalmente "digitado" e mudar de foco (tipo evento onchange do javaScript).

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use o evento `Leave` do `TextBox`.

Ex.:

```
public void textbox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Fazer alguma coisa
}
```

Comment: É o mesmo caso que comentei na reposta abaixo.

Comment: Provavelmente não existe o evento que você está procurando...

Comment: Tem como verificar se o campo foi modificado, existe alguma propriedade?

Comment: Acho que tem. Só um minuto @MarcosVinicius

Comment: @MarcosVinicius usa uma flag no textchange para mudar ela para true, indicando que o controle foi alterado. no evento leave verifique se a flag estiver true ai executa sua lógica e passa a flag para false.

Comment: É uma ideia.. Obrigado!

Comment: Uma observação, tenho meus campos todos em um bindingSource. Talvez por ele eu consiga algo.

Answer (score 0):

O evento OnChange do js no c# é a propriedade "Validating", é a mesma coisa, no lugar do TextChange, utilize o Validating.

Comment: Com o Validating se não mudar o valor do campo e mudar de foco ele é executado. Ou seja se eu tenho um fomulário e usuario ir pressionando a tecla entrer (mudar de foco) irá disparar evento de todos os campos. Não acho que seja ideal.

Comment: Ai você vai precisar colocar uma validação a mais amigão, a linguagem nunca vai saber quando o usuário digitou realmente algo válido, você precisa dizer quando é um valor valido e ainda dar continuidade com o processo.

Comment: Ok, vou dar mais uma pesquisada e volto pra dar um retorno.

Comment: Decidi usar o evento leave em alguns casos e o textChange em outros. vlw pelas dicas! @jbueno